# Spring 3.2 Default for @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

What is the default autowire method for Spring 3.2? so let's say I have this class

```
public class Saxophonist implements IPerform{

    @Override
    public String perform() {
        return "I am A Saxophonist and I am Playing The : "+ saxophone;
    }

    private Instrument saxophone;

    public Instrument getSaxophone() {
        return saxophone;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSaxophone(Instrument saxophone) {
        this.saxophone = saxophone;
    }
}
```

Will it perform byName or will it perform byType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Autowired` is type-driven but it provides a fallback catch to inject bean by name.
Use `@Resource` if you want to perform a bean lookup and injection based on name, alternatively `@Autowired` along with `@Qualifier` can work as well, even though it is more useful when grouping beans.
http://www.spiritwalker-jiang.com/archive/2013/02/11/Understanding-Autowired-annation-in-Spring

Answer (score 2):

By default autowiring is performed by type.  You can use `@Qualifier` to specify a name for autowiring.

When more than one bean of the same type exists in the container Spring will fallback to the name.  So if the fields name matches the bean name, the respective bean will be used.

> For a fallback match, the bean name is considered a default qualifier
>   value. Thus you can define the bean with an id "main" instead of the
>   nested qualifier element, leading to the same matching result.
>   However, although you can use this convention to refer to specific
>   beans by name, @Autowired is fundamentally about type-driven injection
>   with optional semantic qualifiers. This means that qualifier values,
>   even with the bean name fallback, always have narrowing semantics
>   within the set of type matches; they do not semantically express a
>   reference to a unique bean id. Good qualifier values are "main" or
>   "EMEA" or "persistent", expressing characteristics of a specific
>   component that are independent from the bean id, which may be
>   auto-generated in case of an anonymous bean definition like the one in
>   the preceding example.

Comment: What is the fallback for Autowired? and how can I set the default methodology for @Autowired to byName rather than byType?

Answer (score 1):

It will perform lookup by its type. If you have multiple beans of the same type within the same ApplicationContext, you should use `@Qualifier` to autowire all those beans by their respective names.

Answer (score 0):

By type. To make it to perform by name wiring you have to add annotations `@Qualifier`

Comment: what is the fallback for @Autowired?

Answer (score 0):

`bean name` is considered a default qualifier value if added `@Qualifier()`to the setter method. for [more](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)